# C# - No Intellisense for SqlMethods (Linq/EntityFramework)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've seen numerous examples for SqlMethods.Like and want to try it, but I can't get intellisense to recognize it.  What do I need to reference or what "usings" statements to do I need to add.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out:

Add Reference System.Data.Linq, add code:

> using System.Data.Linq.SqlClient

Answer (score 4):

See you've already answered this but for future reference in visual studio if you cursor over the code and press ctrl+. visual studio will recommend you a namespace to use.

Hope this helps you in the future.